# Guest account asking password

Tags: guest-session

Hi gone through strange issue . guest account asked me a password after I have selected lock screen option from top panel . give a try with guest or enter but Nothing up

Comment: You might be affected by this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1022858

Answer (score 1):

While this might be a bug... to work around it I have found that if you click on "switch user" then select the guest account you will get back in with no problems